# PHP Login System Problem On Sessions!

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication, logout

I have a few questions about sessions and login/logout systems.

In my system, first I am  checking whether the user data(username and password) are correct or not. If so i am registering a session: `$_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1` then I assume is logged in and I always check whether `$_SESSION['loggedin']` 1 or not.

However, I recently observe that after one of the users logged in, let's say they go to their page: `/profile.php?u=newuser` but when they are in their own page if they are happen to change the url to this: /`profile.php?u=newuser2` my system assumes that newuser2 is loggedin now :( How could i solve this problem? What would be the best and secure way to log users in?

And lastly, would following way work? Let's say I register `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;` In here $username data is retrieved from database. And in order to understand a user logged in or not I always retrive username from database and check `$_SESSION['username'] == username`. Would this be logical? Would always getting the username from database be efficient?

Comment: You don't need to pass the username around in the URLs.  Just store it in the session when they login, and check to see if the session has a username set, rather than being 1, use the value in the session as the username if it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the session data is stored on the server, there should be no problem with storing the username in $_SESSION and checking against it as you said.

It would be better to store the user id, but it's not a big deal to be honest. Unless you allow users to change their username of course.

profile.php should not have a $_GET variable deciding who to edit. It should automatically use the person logged in. i.e.

Instead of going

```
$username = $_GET['u'];
```

You should be using

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Comment: So am i gonna check $_SESSION['username'] == $_GET['u']? If this is correct then users is loggedin, right?

Comment: No you shouldn't be using $_GET['u'] you should go if( isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ) { echo 'logged in!'; }

Comment: The problem is that, ok I set the $_SESSION['username'] when the user login. if that user goes the someone else's page it can still see the other user's private features. How can I make it protect while only checking, isset($_SESSION['username'])?

Comment: BTW, what I am doing is setting $_SESSION['username'] as the logged in users' username. Anything I miss here?

Comment: In that case yes you should go $_SESSION['username'] == $_GET['u'] and yes, you are right $_SESSION['username'] is the logged in user's username